# Ada: How to override a subprogram of an interface

Tags: inheritance, interface, overriding, ada

In the following code:

```
with Ada.Text_IO;    use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Containers; use Ada.Containers;
with Ada.Containers.Vectors;

procedure Main is

   package IEnumerators is
      -- An umbrella class for all things that are iterable
      type IEnumerator is interface;
      procedure Move_Next (Self : in out IEnumerator) is abstract;
   end IEnumerators;
   use IEnumerators;

   package IEnumerables is
      -- The iterator for IEnumerator
      type IEnumerable is interface;
      function Get_Enumerator
        (Self : IEnumerable) return IEnumerator is abstract;
   end IEnumerables;
   use IEnumerables;

   package Lists is
      -- An IEnumerable whose underlying is a vector

      package Integer_Vector is new Ada.Containers.Vectors
        (Element_Type => Integer, Index_Type => Positive, "=" => "=");

      -- FAIL: type must be declared abstract or "Get_Enumerator" overridden
      -- Fair enough, there's a problem with Get_Enumerator in the body
      type List is new IEnumerable with record
         Members : Integer_Vector.Vector;
      end record;
   end Lists;

   package body Lists is

      type List_Enumerator is new IEnumerator with null record;

      overriding procedure Move_Next (Self : in out List_Enumerator) is
      begin
         null; -- do something
      end Move_Next;

      overriding
         -- FAIL: subprogram "Get_Enumerator" is not overriding. 
         function Get_Enumerator (Self : List) return List_Enumerator
      is
         Result : List_Enumerator;
      begin
         return Result;
      end Get_Enumerator;
   end Lists;

begin
   null;
end Main;
```

I don't understand why the overriding Get-Enumerator fails; it has the same signature as the one in the package IEnumerables (List is a concrete IEnumerable and List_Enumerator is a concrete IEnumerator).

Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 4):

First, the compiler complains about the spec, because you don't override `Get_Enumerator`

package Lists is
-- An IEnumerable whose underlying is a vector

```ada
  package Integer_Vector is new Ada.Containers.Vectors
    (Element_Type => Integer, Index_Type => Positive, "=" => "=");

  type List is new IEnumerable with record
     Members : Integer_Vector.Vector;
  end record;

  overriding
  function Get_Enumerator
    (Self : List) return IEnumerator;
```

Second, the compiler complains in the body, because the overriding must be in the spec (where the type declaration is), and you also have the wrong signature. Ada does not support co-derivation:

```ada
  -- same signature as the parent
  -- overriding is usually not indicated in both spec and body
  function Get_Enumerator (Self : List) return IEnumerator
  is
     Result : List_Enumerator;
  begin
     return Result; -- now this won't compile, wrong type
  end Get_Enumerator;
```

Third, you're not returning the correct type according to the inherited signature, like I said above, Ada does not support co-derivation. You can, however, tell the compiler you want to return IEnumerator, or any type derived from IEnumerator, like so:

```ada
package IEnumerables is
   -- The iterator for IEnumerator
   type IEnumerable is interface;
   function Get_Enumerator
     (Self : IEnumerable) return IEnumerator'Class is abstract;
end IEnumerables;
```

and the overriding in `Lists` spec:

```ada
  overriding
  function Get_Enumerator
    (Self : List) return IEnumerator'Class
```

and `Lists` body:

```ada
  function Get_Enumerator (Self : List) return IEnumerator'Class
  is
     Result : List_Enumerator;
  begin
     return Result;
  end Get_Enumerator;
```